# Categories and tags for powerbi reports

Tags: powerbi

Is there a way to add custom categories and tags to PowerBI reports?

I'm trying to build a self-sustaining catalogue of enterprise reports (which would be a report on its own). PowerBI API provides a list of reports, URLs and descriptions but I would want to be able to group them by one or several categories and make them searchable using tags (ideally, users could add their own tags).

I was not able to find any available mechanism to enable this functionality. Was thinking about adding the words "categories" and "tags" to the description field and parsing it later. Another possible way is to let users add tags using a powerapp and store them as a separate table related to the PowerBI API's output. It feels like there should be a better way of doing this.

Would appreciate other ideas. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since there were no other ideas, I ended up developing a simple powerapp.
If anyone is interested, this is how it all works:

- python script queries [PowerBI activity log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-auditing) and saves reports/tabs stats (time, user, report, tab - these stats are used to build usage report) as well as a list of current reports with their descriptions in my production workspace.
- powerapp works with a simple .csv file with report id and its related categories, tags; anyone can add tags, admins can also assign/alter categories.
- powerbi connects to both data sources, allows to filter, search reports by tags ([here](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/wa104380752?tab=overview) is a nice tagcloud visual) and add new tags.